Intuitively, why does $I(\lambda)$ decay as $\lambda \to \infty$ if $\Phi$ is not constant?
I'm quoting a few lines from Sogge's Fourier Integrals in Classical Analysis.

Stationary phase is of central importance in classical analysis since integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
I(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i \lambda \Phi(y)} a(y) \, dy, \quad \lambda > 0, \tag{1.1.1}
\end{equation}
arise naturally in many problems. The purpose of this section is to study such integrals when $\Phi \in C^\infty$ is real and $a \in C^\infty_0$.
If $\Phi$ is not constant, the factor $e^{i \lambda \Phi(y)}$ becomes highly oscillatory as $\lambda \to \infty$, and, on account of this, one expects $I(\lambda)$ to decay as $\lambda$ becomes large.

Perhaps the last sentence will be quantified later in the book, but it is not intuitively clear to me why $e^{i \lambda \Phi(y)}$ becomes "highly oscillatory" (what do we even mean by this?) as $\lambda \to \infty$ and how this guarantees decay for $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda$ becomes large.

Perhaps, one can get some intution by studying/calculating integrals $\int_{a}^{b}e^{i\lambda x}dx$ as $\lambda\to\infty$. "High oscillations" here mean that the integrand changes signs very often and despite the fact that the absolute value is always 1, the integral is still small (motto: "oscillations lead to lots of cancellations"). A similar intuition can be applied to some extent when you have $e^{i\lambda \Phi(x)}$ with non-constant $\Phi(x)$. Note that when $\Phi$ is constant, then the siutuation is very different.

Yes, and for the decay one can "argue" as follows: the changes of the sign/phase of $e^{i\lambda\Phi(x)}$ happen on much shorter scales than changes of the values of $a(x)$. This kind of forces the integral to decay (again, "oscillations imply cancellations").

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4692008/121671


but it is not intuitively clear to me why $e^{i \lambda \Phi(y)}$ becomes "highly oscillatory" (what do we even mean by this?) as $\lambda \to \infty$

It means it wiggles really fast.

and how this guarantees decay for $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda$ becomes large.

As richrow suggests in the comments we can build intuition by calculating simple examples. I will stick to the case $n = 1$ and $\Phi(y) = y$ for simplicity but the idea generalizes. In fact let's start with richrow's nice example
$$\int_a^b e^{i \lambda x} \, dx.$$
Actually this example is almost too nice because it can be integrated exactly which is saving us from having to think about it. So let's say something about what can be expected intuitively and then do the integral exactly and check that it works out. What happens as $\lambda \to \infty$ is that the integrand wiggles really fast; that is, $e^{i \lambda x}$ has period $\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ and so as $\lambda \to \infty$ we find ourselves integrating over many periods, as many as can fit in the interval $[a, b]$ (so around $\frac{(b - a) \lambda}{2\pi}$).
The integral over a period is zero (this is really the key point), so nearly the entire integral cancels itself out; this is "oscillations cancel" as richrow says. Once we've integrated over all complete periods inside $[a, b]$, the remaining part of the interval has length less than $\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$, and since the integrand is absolutely bounded by $1$, the above integral is absolutely bounded by $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. So we get $O \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} \right)$ decay as $\lambda \to \infty$, for quite general reasons.
Now let's do the exact integral and check that it reproduces this result. Of course it is just
$$\int_a^b e^{i \lambda x} \, dx = \frac{e^{i \lambda b} - e^{i \lambda a}}{i \lambda}$$
which is absolutely bounded by $\frac{2}{\lambda}$, slightly better than we expected.
Now why should we expect something like this to continue to hold for a much more complicated Fourier integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i \lambda x} a(x) \, dx$? The reason is that as $\lambda \to \infty$, the oscillatory factor $e^{i \lambda x}$ is wiggling so fast that from its perspective (that is, after scaling outward by a factor of $\lambda$ so we match how fast it's wiggling) the function $a(x)$ is now changing much more slowly by comparison. In fact as long as $a(x)$ is reasonably smooth ($C^{\infty}$ is more than enough), $\lambda$ can become so big that from the perspective of $e^{i \lambda x}$ it runs through many periods before $a(x)$ has meaningfully changed at all, meaning $a(x)$ is approximately locally constant in small regions and the above analysis approximately applies to it. In other words, we can hope to approximate $a(x)$ by a sum of step functions and then apply the above analysis to each of these step functions. (Much more precise statements than this can be made, which I am not familiar with in detail, but this is just to give the idea.)
The multidimensional case with oscillatory factor something like $e^{i \lambda \langle y, v \rangle}$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be, intuitively at least, reduced to the $1$-dimensional case by reducing to step functions again (by which I mean finite sums of indicator functions of rectangles), then writing multidimensional step functions as products of $1$-dimensional step functions and separating variables to reduce the integral to a product of $1$-dimensional integrals. Then you can hope to reduce the case of a general $\Phi(y)$ to the linear case by a change of variables, as Mittens does in their linked answer.
